# no username on login screen

Tags: 12.10, server

When I get to the login screen for Ubuntu 12.10, it asks for me to type in my username which I thought I knew but apparently its wrong. When I log into quest, everything is fine except I need a password for authentication. I cant recover my password without username either.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack; but if you switch to recovery mode and go into the shell (NOT THE BOOT SHELL), you can run:

`cat /etc/passwd | grep home`

and get the users that have a home directory. You should be one of them; look for something familiar. This happened to me and that's how I solved it.